# Android, Google Spread Sheet crashes when on menu button is pressed

Tags: java, android, logcat

Hey guys i have an issue with my current application, The issue is that for some reason whenever i try clicking the "Save Register" button within my menu the application crashes. It is saying println message but i am sure i have placed hello world in a String?

I would like to mention that i have been following a tutorial found on Youtube posting data to google spreadsheets and other tutorials to create this AP manager, You may have noticed within my code but the next step is to Save the array list into the spread sheet which is the next step. However for now i would i cannot simply get the menu button to save the "Hello World" message into Spreadsheets

My Log Cat shows:

```
Process: com.example.gavin.wifiattendance, PID: 2266
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
        at com.example.gavin.wifiattendance.MainActivity.postData(MainActivity.java:93)
        at com.example.gavin.wifiattendance.MainActivity.onMenuItemSelected(MainActivity.java:143)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1127)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:165)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
```

My Main activity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

boolean wasApEnabled = false;
static AccessPoint wifiAP;
private WifiManager wifi;
static Button apButton;
static TextView textView;
final String myTag = "DocsUpload";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    apButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleBtn);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiClients);

    apButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            wifiAP.toggleWifiAP(wifi, MainActivity.this);
        }
    });

    wifiAP = new AccessPoint(this);
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    scan();

    //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

}

private void scan(){
    wifiAP.getClientList(false, new FinishScanListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFinishScan(final ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients) {
            textView.setText("WifiApState:" + wifiAP.getWifiApState()+ "\n\n");
            textView.append("Clients: \n");
            for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients){
                textView.append("====================\n");
                textView.append("ipAddress: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddress() + "\n");
                textView.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
                textView.append("macAddress: " + clientScanResult.getMacAddress() + "\n");
                textView.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable() + "\n");

            }
        }
    });
}

public void postData() {

    String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1yipuuXd5V53Ol12U24Cl2H4RIdYtm622jIk13Zo26cM/formResponse";
    HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();
    String col1 = "Hello";
    String col2 = "World";

    String data = "entry_272641491=" + URLEncoder.encode(col1) + "&" +
            "entry_130393492=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2);
    String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl, data);
    Log.i(myTag, response);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (wasApEnabled) {
        if (wifiAP.getWifiApState() != wifiAP.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED && wifiAP.getWifiApState() != wifiAP.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING) {
            wifiAP.toggleWifiAP(wifi, MainActivity.this);
        }
    }
    updateStatusDisplay();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    boolean wifiApIsOn = wifiAP.getWifiApState()==wifiAP.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED || wifiAP.getWifiApState()==wifiAP.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING;
    if (wifiApIsOn){
        wasApEnabled = true;
        wifiAP.toggleWifiAP(wifi, MainActivity.this);
    }else {
        wasApEnabled = false;
    }
    updateStatusDisplay();
}

public static void updateStatusDisplay(){
    if (wifiAP.getWifiApState()==wifiAP.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED || wifiAP.getWifiApState()==wifiAP.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING){
        apButton.setText("Turn Off");
    }else {
        apButton.setText("Turn on");
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,0,0, "Get Clients");
    menu.add(0,1,0, "Save Register");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 0:
            scan();
            break;
        case 1:
            postData();
            break;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

}

Edit: After removing the log, the spread sheet no longer gets any information even when the button is pressed.

```
    03-12 11:41:56.444    1903-1921/com.example.gavin.wifiattendance W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5c08180, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-12 11:41:58.696    1903-1903/com.example.gavin.wifiattendance D/WifiAttendance﹕ Setting httpPost headers
03-12 11:41:58.696    1903-1903/com.example.gavin.wifiattendance D/Your App Name Here﹕ https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1yipuuXd5V53Ol12U24Cl2H4RIdYtm622jIk13Zo26cM/formResponse?entry_272641491=Hello&entry_130393492=World
03-12 11:41:58.697    1903-1903/com.example.gavin.wifiattendance E/WifiAttendance﹕ HttpUtils: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-12 11:41:58.697    1903-1903/com.example.gavin.wifiattendance D/WifiAttendance﹕ Returning value:null
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a null string to Log.i in postData.  Don't do that.  Its almost certainly because HTTP requests are asynchronous and you don't have a response yet.  Since its just a log I'd delete the line.

Comment: Hello tht has solved my problem but after i remove it, it would not send any data at all to the spread sheet. im getting this message in logcat which i will create an edit for in my original message